# Avro Records with Unknown Key Names and Quantity but Known Values

Tags: avro

I am looking to convert JSON to Avro without altering the shape of the data

A nested field in the JSON contains a variable number of keys, which are never known in advance. The record that branches off of each of these unknown nodes however is of known, well-defined shape.

An example of this input data is as shown below

```
{
  "customers": {
    "paul_ince": {
      "name": "Mr Paul Ince",
      "age": 54
    },
    "kim_kardashian": {
      "name": "Ms Kim Kardashian",
      "age": 41
    },
    "elon_musk": {
      "name": "Elon Musk, Technoking of Tesla",
      "age": 50
    }
}
```

Now it would be more avro friendly of course to have customers lead to an array of the form

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "customer_name": "paul_ince",
      "name": "Mr Paul Ince",
      "age": 54
    },
    { 
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

But this would violate my constraint that the shape of the input data be unchanged.

This problem seems to manifest itself frequently if I rely on data from external sources or scrapes, or preexisting data that was never created for Avro.

In my head, the schema would look something like the below,

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "customers",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "customers",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": $customer_name,
            "type": {
              "type": "record",
              "name": $customer_name,
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "name",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                {
                  "name": "age",
                  "type": "int"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

where `$customer_name` is an assignment value, defined on read. Just asking the question it feels like this violates fundamental avro but I *must* use Avro and I *strongly desire* to maintain the input shape of the data. It would be highly impractical to modify this, not least given how frequently this problem appears and how large and varied the data I need to transfer from JSON to Avro is